# How do I stop my button from disappearing upon onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm learning as I go through this project; apologies if I've overlooked the obvious.

My goal: a button over an image; this button runs a javascript function to select a random quote from an array and display it. So far, so good.

The problem: The displayed quote makes both image and button vanish.

Most examples I've found in my searching have improper use of .write as the issue. I have yet to find someone with precisely my problem. I do know now to avoid that, though! I tried following up my code with a div that had the variable as an id, to no avail. I also just tried moving things around with line breaks. I'm at a loss after some hours of Googling.

I've not touched CSS yet. My javascript is as follows:

```
var spark = [
"Sample 1",
"Sample 2",
"Sample 3",
]
function newSpark() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (spark.length));
document.getElementById('sparkDisplay').innerHTML = spark[randomNumber];
}
```

and my pertinent HTML, first in the head, then in the body:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
    }
    
    .container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .container .btn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      color: rgb(227, 240, 48);
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 24px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container .btn:hover {
      background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
```

```
<h2>Jar of Sparks</h2>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="sparkDisplay">
    <img src="jarpic.jpg" alt="a jar of fireflies in a starless night" style="width:100%">
    <button onclick="newSpark()" class="btn">grasp a spark</button>
</div>
```

Any pointers to put me on the right track would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this line
`document.getElementById('sparkDisplay').innerHTML = spark[randomNumber];`

you are replacing the both image and the button which are also using `sparkDisplay` element with your quote, it is better to create a new div and add that quote to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the innerHTML on #sparkDisplay. If you move the button and img outside of the div with id sparkDisplay the button and img will then be consistant.

```
<div class="container" id="sparkDisplay">

</div>
<div class="container >
    <img src="jarpic.jpg" alt="a jar of fireflies in a starless night" style="width:100%">
    <button onclick="newSpark()" class="btn">grasp a spark</button>
</div>
```